# Why can´t we import Mobileconnect SMS contacts from data extension in automation studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, automation, mobileconnect

We have created a "contacts" data extension. Have three fileds, an ID (subscriber key), mobile number and locale.
We need to import these contacts to use them in SMS in automation studio.
To do this, we have created an Import Definition in Mobileconnect. This defines the conctacts data extension like source and a list created like target.
In automation studio we have used "Import Mobile Contacs" activity, that uses this Import Definition.
But when we run the automation, we receive an error.

Why?

Comment: Please post your specific error and we'll have a look.

Comment: Is there any way to know code error or similar?

Comment: We only view the message "Errored Finishing STEP 1: "

Comment: OK, I agree that's not helpful.  Could you run the Step 1 activity manually outside of Automation Studio and report back?  We may get something more useful that way.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you are using the right value for locale. Locale values for field type "locale" in the data extension does not match the locale in Mobile connect.

In example:

Locale value for UK in a field in data extension type locale--> **en-GB**

Locale value for UK in the field locale in Mobile connect--> **GB**

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

I've just run into this problem today.  It turns out that your Data Extension should be using a text field for "Locale", and insert the correct value into it (such as AU for Australia instead of en-aus).  This allows you to run the import into a MobileConnect list correctly.